# jQuery - fadeOut on Scroll / fadeIn on "scrollstop"

Tags: jquery, scroll, fadein, fadeout

I have a div positioning working which gets fired by the scroll-event. What happens it that the scroll event gets fired a bunch of times which results in a flickering div. My plan is to fade out that div and fade back in as soon as no more scroll event is fired. How can I check that scrolling is over? I thought about a combination of timeout <-> scroll but actually nothing worked as I hoped. Here's what i got so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //var animActive = false;

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        /*
        if (animActive == false){
            animActive = true;
            $('.mceExternalToolbar').fadeOut(100, function () {
                $('.mceExternalToolbar').fadeIn(3000, function () {
                    animActive = false;
                    console.log("NOW");
                });
            });
        }
        */

        topParentx = $('#tinyMCEwrapper').position().top;
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= topParentx){
            $('.mceExternalToolbar').css('top', ($(this).scrollTop()-topParentx) + "px");
        } else {
            $('.mceExternalToolbar').css('top', "0px");
        };
    });

});
```

As you can see I left one of my last attempts in there, but the callbacks of the fade-function didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no concept of scroll-stop so you can't really trigger an animation from that. What may work better is to instead animate the 'top' property of your div so that it smoothly slides to it's new position instead of flickering.

```
        topParentx = $('#tinyMCEwrapper').position().top;
        var topTarget = "0px";
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= topParentx){
            topTarget = ($(this).scrollTop()-topParentx) + "px";
        }
        $('.mceExternalToolbar').stop().animate({top, topTarget}, 500);
```

Comment: Hey thx... This isnt what i planned but i must admit, that its working far better... Especially never stumbled upon the stop() function before which is very very handy in that case... so THANK YOU... To make your example working with my version of jquery a quick look in the reference wwas needed because the css definition must be called as:

   $('.mceExternalToolbar').stop().animate({top: topTarget}, 200);


Thanks!!! That helped me a lot!!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you, thanks for the update and code fix. I've updated my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery special events for creating a scrollstop event. James Padolsey has written a great [example of scrollstop event](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/).

Answer (score 1):

Fix to not pulse on scroll! settimeout

```
var animActive = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if (animActive == false){
        animActive = true;
        $('#target').fadeOut(100, function () {
            var scrl = setTimeout( function(){
            animActive = false;
            $('#target').fadeIn(500);
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok while i was happy yesterday... Reality stroke back today... SAFARI reacts with not re-rendering all necessary fragments behind the moving div. Especially over tinyMCE's iframe.
So i ended up with the following and this works quite well. Fades out the div -> animation to position -> Fade in only if callback is fired..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        topParentx = $('#tinyMCEwrapper').position().top;

        var topTarget = "0px";

        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= topParentx){
            topTarget = ($(this).scrollTop()-topParentx) + "px";
            $('.mceExternalToolbar').animate({opacity: 0}, 1);
        }
        $('.mceExternalToolbar').stop().animate({top: topTarget}, 200, 'swing', function(){
            $('.mceExternalToolbar').animate({opacity: 1}, 100, 'swing');

        });

    });

});
```