# Can I keep a DIV always on the screen, but not always in a fixed position?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have a master form for my website, and I want to dock a div to the top of the content area inside the master form. This div should always be visible despite scroll position. Is this possible?

A picture would explain it better.

[image]

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL <3 http://www.balsamiq.com/

Comment: I was bored...do you mean like this?   http://makeagif.com/i/8qut0B

Comment: This effect requires JavaScript, is that an issue?

Comment: @zzzzBov I don't have a problem with using javascript providing that the div is still at the top of the content area when javascript is disabled.

Comment: try this out http://jsfiddle.net/YpKTP/

Comment: @zzzzBov Thank you very much for that sample, it helped me troubleshoot why I kept getting jumpy scroll behavior when my content height was about the same size as my scroll area. If you post it as an answer, I'd give you an upvote

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I posted a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/YpKTP/) as a comment, so I suppose I'll write out a full answer to this.

The markup is pretty straight-forward, but there are some important notes for each section.

#### HTML

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header-inner"> <!-- Note #1 -->
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- Some Content Here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#page {
    padding: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}

#header,
#header-inner { /* Note #1 */
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}

.scrolling { /* Note #2 */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
//jQuery used for simplicity
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('#header-inner').toggleClass('scrolling', $(window).scrollTop() > $('#header').offset().top);

  //can be rewritten long form as:
  var scrollPosition, headerOffset, isScrolling;
  scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
  headerOffset = $('#header').offset().top;
  isScrolling = scrollPosition > headerOffset;
  $('#header-inner').toggleClass('scrolling', isScrolling);
});
```

### Note #1

The scrolling header will be attached to the top of the page using `position: fixed`, but this style will remove the content from content flow, which will cause the content to jump unless its container maintains the original height.

### Note #2

Styles belong in CSS, however it may be difficult to properly align some elements with their original position. You may need to dynamically set the `left` or `right` css property via JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry for posting a late comment, but I'm new to JS. What exactly is content flow?

Comment: @ForgetfulFellow, that's a CSS question. [The spec outlines "normal flow"](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow), but the tl;dr is that content added to a page will cause other content after it to flow vertically. Content that's removed from the normal flow, such as by absolutely positioning an element, will no longer cause the content around it to be pushed down the page.

Comment: This is great!  One weird thing.  If the page is scrolled down and you then reload the page, `#header-inner` will be at the top of the page even though `#header` is below (at least on Chrome). Scrolling the page fixes it, but it looks funny initially.

Comment: This answer is severely out-of-date. At this point `position: sticky` addresses the issue directly from CSS.

Answer (score 9):

As of July 2018 it is time to revisit this issue. `position: sticky` was introduced exactly for problems like yours, and has [decent browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

It works like this:

```
<div style="position: sticky; top: 0;"> Header </div>
```

where `top` is the distance to the viewport top the div should stay at when you scroll. **Specifying `top` is mandatory.** Other options like `bottom`, `left` or `right` do *not* work currently.

The sticky div will act like a normal div in all ways except when you scroll past it, then it will stick to the top of the browser.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9caexj7b/32/) to give you an idea.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need jQuery or the like, see my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SeeTS/25/)

**Edit**

jQuery function, where `.form` is the content div and `.banner` is the div that is docked

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    t = $('.form').offset();
    t = t.top;

    s = $(window).scrollTop();

    d = t-s;

    if (d < 0) {
        $('.banner').addClass('fixed');
        $('.banner').addClass('paddingTop');
    } else {
        $('.banner').removeClass('fixed');
        $('.banner').removeClass('paddingTop');
    }
});

.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.paddingTop{
    padding-top:110px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm accepting your answer because you took into account the offset for the master form's header rather than hardcoding it. Also, hope you don't mind but I'm going to add the jQuery function to your answer.

Comment: keep the CSS in CSS files. use `addClass`, `removeClass`, or `toggleClass` instead.

Comment: @ptriek This actually gives me really jumpy scroll behavior if the height of the content is close to the scrollable area. I think it's becauase removing the docked div from the visual tree is changing the scroll position, which is firing the onScroll a 2nd time.

Comment: fixed that by adding padding-top to the form when the banner is positioned: http://jsfiddle.net/SeeTS/25/

Comment: @ptriek That doesn't work, it still is jumpy. I fixed it by adding a ghost div of the same size behind the header, which stays while the inner header moves.

Comment: Really simple.  Really helpful. +1

Answer (score 3):

I created a new fiddle which I hope can be useful. The DIV can be arbitrary positioned in the page and stays visible when scrolling.

http://jsfiddle.net/mM4Df/

```
<div id="mydiv">
  fixed div
</div>

<div class="ghost">
  fixed div
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mydiv { position: fixed;  background-color:Green; float:left; width:100%}
.ghost{opacity: 0}
```

probably there is a better solution than using a "ghost" but I do not know which.

Comment: That's close, however the div is fixed and doesn't scroll with the rest of the page. It should stay at the top of the content area until the top of the content area leaves the page. Then it should be docked to the top of the page.

Comment: I see. Probably the JavaScript solution is better then.

Comment: +1 for giving me the "ghost" solution. I realize now I need something like that in place to prevent jumpy scroll behavior

Answer (score 3):

Assume the top position(to the top of the screen) of the header div is 100px in the beginning, you can do like this: 
if the scroll top of window is over 100px, set the header div to fix position with top 0px;
if the scroll top of window is less than 100px, set the position of the header div with the default layout.
With jquery, it is sth like this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('div#header').css({ 
            "position" : 'fixed',
            "top" : 0 });
    } else {
        $('div#header').css({ "position" : 'relative', "top" : 0 });
    }
});
```

it is implemented with the scroll event.

Comment: +1 for the right idea and working jQuery, although I'm accepting ptriek's answer since it doesn't require hard-coding the height, and can be attached to a div element instead of the main form.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to fix its position.

Assuming your `<div>` has an ID "topdiv":

```
#topdiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
```

Note you'll have to set a margin-top for the content, because the fixed div will display "over" the content:

```
#contentarea { margin-top: 35px; }
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/29VeC/).

Comment: My problem with that is my master form has a header of it's own, which can scroll off the page. So my header div is not always docked at the top of the page.

Comment: What if there is some stuff before the fixed div?

Comment: Hm there was no such thing on your mock-up. It depends a bit on the actual markup I guess, my answer was a bit generic. Could you provide more info like markup and current styling ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a header div with two properties:

1. When it would normally be visible, it stays in its default position.
2. When it would normally be invisible, it appears at the top of the screen.

In short, something a little bit like "max-top" (which doesn't exist as a css property).

If you want to do all of that, the quickest way may involve some JavaScript.
Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654792/jquery-fadeout-on-scroll-fadein-on-scrollstop#1654825); if I get some time later I'll update this with some more code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a div that follows when you scroll down. This implementation can be seen for shopping carts on number of sites. You may want to look at http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/

Another good link is: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/

Some related collection of scroll examples: http://webdesign14.com/30-tutorials-and-plugins-jquery-scroll/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this CSS. Maybe it is what you are looking for:

```
    html, body{
        text-align:center;
        margin:0px;
        background:#ABCFFF;
        height:100%;
        }
    .header-cont {
        width:100%;
        position:fixed;
        top:0px;
    }
    #header {
        height:50px;
        background:#F0F0F0;
        border:1px solid #CCC;
        width: 100%;
        margin:auto;
    }
    .content-cont {
        width:100%;
        position:absolute; /* to place it somewhere on the screen */
        top:60px;
        bottom:60px; /* makes it lock to the bottom */
        overflow:auto;
    }
    #content {
        background:#F0F0F0;
        border:1px solid #CCC;
        width:960px;
        position:relative;  
        min-height:99.6%;
        height:auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin:auto;            
    }
    .footer-cont {
        width:100%;
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0px;
    }
    #footer {
        height:50px;
        background:#F0F0F0;
        border:1px solid #CCC;
        width: 100%;
        margin:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in this modified example banner div stays in the screen when scrolling and also stays in the container div.
when the container divs bottom reaches to the top of the screen, banner div returns to relative position and scrolls up with container
http://jsfiddle.net/SeeTS/198/

JQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
t = $('.form').offset();
t = t.top;
s = $(window).scrollTop();
d = t-s;
b = $('.banner').height();
f = $('.form').height();

if (d < 5) {
    if(d < -(f-b)-15)
        {
        $('.banner').addClass('bottom');
        $('.banner').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    else {
        $('.banner').addClass('fixed');
        $('.banner').removeClass('bottom');
    }
}
else {
    $('.banner').removeClass('fixed');

}
});
```

CSS

```
    .form {
    position:relative;
    width:480px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    padding:10px;
}
p {
  border:2px dotted #000;
}
.banner {
    border-radius:8px;
    background:#660000;
    height:100px;
    width:60px;
}
.fixed{
    position:fixed;
    top:5px;
}
.bottom {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="form" id="form">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="70px">
      <div class="banner"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus...</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div style="position:relative;height:500px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked for me:

`HTML`

```
<div class="sticky">
    ...
</div>
```

`CSS`

```
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```