# Always visible div while scrolling

Tags: html, visibility

On my aspx page, I have two left and right portions. I want to show always left side (which is actually a 'div' containig treeview) while scrolling the right side (which are actual contents of page). Thanks

Comment: please select your prefered answer @M Usman Shafique

Answer (score 23):

You need to put `position: fixed;` on the div element. That will anchor it to the viewport.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm using ie7 where position:fixed is not working

Comment: Forget about ie7 and Old versions it's a waste of time ,dude ;)

Comment: What you gonna do when div's height is large than viewport.

Answer (score 21):

Hi I found the best solution! As always JQUERY saving my life !!

Just put a Div called as you wan, I've chosen the same in the example below: #scrollingDiv.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $().ready(function() {
        var $scrollingDiv = $("#scrollingDiv");

        $(window).scroll(function(){            
            $scrollingDiv
                .stop()
                .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() )}, "slow" );         
        });
    });
</script>
```

I took that code from a website, it works and it's pretty easy to understand.

Answer (score 16):

Fast forward to 2020, and it is now possible to do this with CSS.

```
<div style="position: sticky; top: 0;"> Tree view </div>
```

[The user npas explains this quite nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51495214/1171227):

> `top` is the distance to the viewport top the div should stay at when you scroll. Specifying `top` is mandatory. (…)
>
> The sticky div will act like a normal div in all ways except when you scroll past it, then it will stick to the top of the browser.
>
> Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9caexj7b/32/) to give you an idea.

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Supported by [all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the position of the div to Fixed in CSS. See [this link](http://www.wickham43.net/divboxes.php) for more information. You will need to set position using the top and left in css as well so it knows where to fix it!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when the block moves, it gets attention and ability to concentrate on reading.

To remedy this using this function.

This code is perfect :

(change "220" and "46px" if necessary)

```
  var $scrollingDiv = $("#scrollingDiv");

$(window).scroll(function(){     
if ($(window).scrollTop()>220)       {
            $scrollingDiv
                .css("position",'fixed' )  
                .css("top",'46px' )           
        } else {
 $scrollingDiv
                .css("position",'' )    
                .css("top",'' )             
        }
        });
```