# Change margin-top position of an fixed positioned element after reaching the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change top-margin of an fixed div element from margin-top: 200px to margin top 0px after reaching the bottom of the page (or 200px from bottom) using vertical scrollbar.

And toggle return back if scrolling back to the top.

I guess some javascript/jQuery code code do that.

my html/layout code:

```
<div id="header" style="position: fixed; margin-top: 0px;">
     Header content
</div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="left" style="position: fixed; margin-top: 200px;">Google Ads here</div>
    <div id="right">Content posts here</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    Footer content
</div>
```

**EDIT: Here are some images to make my question more clear.**

1. normal state when you load the page:
   [image]
2. problem when you scroll down, and the google ads column is in conflict with footer:
   [image]
3. how it needs to be solved:
   [image]

Comment: Yes, Javascript could do that.

Comment: An element with position='fixed' is not in the document flow and does not have margins. You can change the top value...

Comment: Can you make me clear? As per my understanding you have a div at 200px from top. You want as you scroll your page it's gradually moving to top. When you scroll at end of document it should be at 0px at top? am i right?

Answer (score 2):

Derfder...

Voila, my proposed solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/YL7Jc/2/

The animation's a tad jerky, but I think it does what you want

(It's my take on an earlier s/o post:
[Can I keep a DIV always on the screen, but not always in a fixed position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418583/can-i-keep-a-div-always-on-the-screen-but-not-always-in-a-fixed-position) )

Let me know what you think!

Comment: What am I missing? Did this not do the trick?  P.S. Thanks for whoever upvoted :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code which binds an event to `window.scroll` to check if the page hits the bottom (bottom in 200px) and moves the `#left` to top (`margin-top: 0`)..

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/6Q6XY/4/ ( added some demo code to see when it hits the bottom.)

```
$(function() {
    var $left = $('#left');

    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {   
        if (($(document).height() 
               - (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight)) < 200) {                
            $left.css('marginTop', 0);
        } else {
            $left.css('marginTop', 200);
        }
    });
});
```

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/6148937/297641

Comment: Hmm, I need something different. I have edited my question with more info and images.

Comment: @Derfder Please post the layout/html and the respective css so we can work with that

Comment: #header and #left are fixed other divs are position: relative and float: left. Styling and margins and z-index is not a problem for me. The only problem is to detect end (start of 200px from bottom) when scrolling down and starting to move the left div with google ads up, so the footer is not interfering with them. And vice versa when I scroll to the top.

Comment: @Derfder It is not for you.. we need to look at your html and css on how you have this `#left` and `#top` fixed. Fix the html in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6Q6XY/5/ as you have in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the window scroll function, this is a jquery implementation so please ensure you include the latest jquery libaries

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

            //if it hits bottom
            $('#left').css("margin-top", "0px");

        }
        else {

            $('#left').css("margin-top", "200px");

        }
    });
```

Comment: not working, even if i change $('#left').css("margin-top", "0px"); for alert("bottom!"; nothing is alerted. I tried it with and without $(document).ready ( function () { //code }); your code is not working ;(

Comment: It does in fact work, maybe if you paste your code so we can check what you are doing wrong [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgjVD/7/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="main" style="width: 960px; margin: 0px auto;"> 
    <div id="left" style="position: fixed; top: 200px; left: 0px; background: #000; width: 100%; color: #fff;">Google Ads here</div> 
    <div id="right"></div> 
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var documentHeight = $(document).height();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var left = $('#left');
        var leftTopPosition = $('#left').css('top');
        leftTopPosition = parseInt(leftTopPosition.substring(0, leftTopPosition.length-2));             

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var pageOffsetY = window.pageYOffset;           
            if((documentHeight - pageOffsetY - windowHeight) <= 200 && leftTopPosition == 200) {
                left.stop().animate({
                    'top': '0px'
                });

                leftTopPosition = 0;
            }

            else if((documentHeight - pageOffsetY - windowHeight) > 200 && leftTopPosition == 0) {
                left.stop().animate({
                    'top': '200px'
                });

                leftTopPosition = 200;
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it tomorrow. Today I ahve too much other work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Firstly you should have been more clearer in the first place before marking people down, as everyone give similar answers then it shows the question was not clear.

See [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Q6XY/32/) for a potential fix, please tweak as you need it with the pixels etc

Answer (score 0):

for this problem you should use z-index in css

Answer (score -1):

Try somethins like this

```
      if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())   
           {
              document.getElementById(yourid).setAttribute("style","margin-top:0px");
           }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
   if(($(window).height()-$(window).scrollTop())<200)
   {
       $('#left').css('margin-top',$(window).scrollTop());
   }
   else
   {
       $('#left').css('margin-top',200);
   }
});
```

Comment: It's making weird stuff. Did you try your code? It makes my page longer and stuff. Not working either ;(.